# What are some good options for saving Cassandra backup taken from AWS S3 to a non-AWS location?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cassandra, google-cloud-storage, rackspace-cloud

I have a Cassandra database backup on AWS S3 already. The backup is being created on daily basis and saved on S3. Now I am looking for a 2nd cloud storage where I can save a copy of my C* backup from AWS S3 regularly. Basically, it's just copying the files (~500 GB in size) from AWS S3 and saving it somewhere in the cloud as a 2nd backup regularly. I am looking for the best option for achieving this goal. Best option in terms of cost effectiveness, flexibility and developer friendliness. I need to be able to write a script that will copy the latest C* backup from AWS S3 and will save it into the 2nd cloud storage. This script needs to be run on regular basis using a cron job or rake task. I have found [Rackspace](http://www.rackspace.com/) and the new comer [Google Compute Engine](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/) after some research. But I am not sure which one to use and how to use. I am seeking some advice in this regard. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT_1**:

ok, so I tried this command:

```
gsutil -m rsync -r s3://<s3_bucket_name>  gs://<GS_bucket_name>
```

I already modified the config file .boto and provided my aws access and secret keys there.

but when I ran the above command, I got this following message which includes an exception:

```
Building synchronization state...
You have requested multiple threads or processes for an operation, but
the required functionality of Python's multiprocessing module is not
available. Your operations will be performed sequentially, and any
requests for parallelism will be ignored. Your max number of open
files, 0, is too low to allow safe multiprocessing. On Linux you can
fix this by adding something like "ulimit -n 10000" to your ~/.bashrc
or equivalent file, and opening a new terminal. On MacOS you can fix
this by running a command like this once: "launchctl limit maxfiles
10000"
ServiceException: Non-MD5 etag ("3fd6e94275941cf4d33768682cd52363-21") present for key <Key: <my_s3_bucket name>,2014-02-18-05-00/disaster-cassandra-1.1/<s3_project_name>/column_attributes/snapshots/1392699667769/<s3_project_name>-column_attributes-ic-1225-Data.db>, data integrity checks are not possible.
Starting synchronization
```

What I am missing here? Any thought?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have a particular bucket in S3 that you need to synchronize periodically into a Google Cloud Storage bucket? That's not too hard. Google Cloud Storage's `gsutil` command-line utility has an `rsync` method which syncs the contents of two buckets. You can sync everything with this command:

```
gsutil rsync -d -r s3://original-bucket gs://google-cloud-bucket
```

Set up gsutil, stick that line into a cron script, and you're done. Keep in mind that the "-d" means it will delete content in GCS if it's been deleted in S3, which you might not want if you're trying to protect against accidental deletions.

(Disclaimer: I have a rather strong conflict of interest and a bias in favor of Google Cloud Storage and can't be counted on to offer objective advice as to which cloud storage solution is superior).

Instructions on installing gsutil: https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install

Comment: Yes, I have a particular S3 bucket where the C* backups are saved incrementally. This sounds like a pretty simpler solution than I thought! Thanks a lot @Brandon. I will give it a try and will get back to you if any issue. And, I will accept the answer as soon as I get this working. +1 for now :-) Thanks again.

Comment: If you have a large number of objects and a reasonably fast network connection you might want to use the gsutil -m option with that command, so it uses multiprocessing to do the synchronization (gsutil -m rsync -d -r s3://original-bucket gs://google-cloud-bucket). Note also that this command will copy the data via whatever host is running gsutil, so you might consider running it on GCE rather than, say, your corporate network.

Comment: while using that command, I actually don't have a static s3 bucket url as that is a protected bucket on aws. 

so when using that command, how can I specify the s3 bucket url? I can access the s3 bucket using aws api from a ruby program for example. Then, how can I run the above command in a cron script? is there any way of doing that?

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on the problem. Could you elaborate? Is the bucket protected by IP address? Or some other policy or feature?

Comment: Please look at my edit message. I explained the problem and where I am now.

Comment: @BrandonYarbrough I was thinking of providing s3 bucket url in the beginning, later figured out that I can just use the bucket names. sorry for the confusion caused by my previous comment. I have edited my question to give you a clear idea where exactly I am now. Please look at the edit and let me know why I am getting that "ServiceException: Non-MD5 etag ("3fd6e94275941cf4d33768682cd52363-21") present for key <Key: <my_s3_bucket name>,2014-02-18-05-00/disaster-cassandra-......" exception message while I run the gsutl command. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi Keen - thanks for including the additional detail. That's a bug; we're working on a fix for it.

Comment: @MikeSchwartz thanks for letting me know. I was not getting any clue after some google search! 
Could you please let me know when can we expect to get this bug fixed? Because I am relying on it you know!

Comment: @MikeSchwartz is the bug fixed by now?

Comment: @MikeSchwartz is there any other tool other than gsutil that I can use to get this done?

Comment: @MikeSchwartz
no update on the bug that you were working on? Just checking. Otherwise, I am going to find some other solution. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply - this is fixed in gsutil 4.3 (which is now available). You'll get a warning message instead of a failure for this case.

Comment: @TravisHobrla thanks a lot for the reply.

Great, I just updated to gsutil 4.3 and yes I am getting warning like this:

Non-MD5 etag ("3fd6e94275941cf4d33768682cd52363-21") present for key <Key: <my_s3_bucket name>,2014-02-18-05-00/disaster-cassandra-1.1/<s3_project_name>/column_attributes/snapshots/1392699667769/<s3_project_name>-column_attributes-ic-1225-Data.db>, data integrity checks are not possible.

But does this mean I will lose some data while taking backup from s3 to cloud storage? Please let me know.

Also how long should it take to run the process for about 500GB data?

Comment: Also, while this command is running:

gsutil -m rsync -r s3://<s3_bucket_name>  gs://<GS_bucket_name>

I am still seeing that warning and if I go to my gs bucket I still don't see any data there. is this normal behaviour? When I should see the backup data on gs bucket? and how long it should take for about 500GB data? Please let me know. Thanks a lot.

Comment: That warning simply means there's no way to ensure the data that you downloaded from s3 is actually the same data you stored on s3 server. Unfortunately since s3 doesn't provide an MD5 or other standard hash for to check against, there's no real way around this (no matter what tool you're using to transfer that data). It's very rare that the data would corrupted during transfer but it can happen.

Comment: @TravisHobrla thanks for the clarification. And what about the time? How long it should it for about 500GB data? I am planning run this script like a cron task on a daily basis to get the backup from s3 to gs every day.

Also, its running for almost 20 minutes now. I still can't see any data in the gs bucket. What's going on here? Could you please explain? Thanks

Comment: As for performance, the time it takes to transfer is going to be dependent on your CPU and network connections to both S3 and GS, so it's hard to provide an estimate. You should see a progress indicator on stderr that shows you how the transfers are going. Each file will show up in the GS bucket when the transfer is complete, so if the files are large, it will take some time. Are you working with 500GB files?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55608/discussion-between-keen-learner-and-travis-hobrla).